# Can't add new posts in Wordpress: memory error

Tags: wordpress, out-of-memory

On my Wordpress installation, I am currently unable to add new posts since updating to the latest version 3.5.2. Clicking *Post > Add New* shows the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /var/www/www.mysite.com/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php on line 306
```

For testing purposes, I have the default template (twenty-eleven) running with all plugins disabled.

I have increased the memory to 512M in php.ini, wp-config.php, and in default-constants.php, but I still can't seem to get past this error (which seems to show an allowance of only 256M).

Just FYI....the database is not new - it has over a thousand posts in it. This issue only occurs for certain admin users, others can see the *Post > Add New* screen but still see the memory issue on other pages in the admin area.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini`? Do you use Apache or fast-cgi, or suhosin patch?

Comment: Using nginx... I'm sure I edited the right php.ini only because confirmed after restart with php_info() and it showed correctly 512MB allocated. Thanks though... it is something I double- and triple-checked.

Comment: Just checking. You did restart the nginx and fast_cgi services right?

Comment: Also since your using nginx would you also happen to be using the php-fpm wrapper? If so, is it running on a socket and if so, (nearly there) can you post the resource allocation conf

Comment: Used "/etc/init.d/nginx restart" and nginx restarted as normal.  Figured it restarted correctly because php_info() updated with the changes I made in php.ini.  I didn't restart fast_cgi though...is that necessary?

Comment: @JoeBuckle Yes, the server is using the php-fpm wrapper.  Unfortunately, I don't know if it's running on a socket...is there a quick way to tell?

Comment: Maybe in /etc/php-fpm.d all the confs should be.

Comment: Im using nginx with fpm too on one server and I had to restart `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart` for changes to take effect

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks, in my case it actually was "php5-fpm": `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart`.  Anyway, after restart, I still receive the same error `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted` unfortunately.  php_info() still shows `memory_limit 512M` which is correct, but Wordpress is failing at 256M as shown in the error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hard work, plus some additional outside help, I have resolved the problem.  It turned out to be an accumulation of meta data under the user accounts that was set to track popup help messages.  It is safely deleted, and once removed, increased the loading speed of the site by about 30% as well as fixed all of the admin issues we were having, including the one listed here.

Simple fix... just run the following query against your WordPress database:

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'dismissed_wp_pointers'
```

I also read the adding a couple of indexes to the meta data can help a bit in performance as well, so if you're looking for a quick tweak, try these two SQL calls as well:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD INDEX USING BTREE (meta_value(255));
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD INDEX USING BTREE (meta_value(255));
```

Hope that helps anyone with the same issues!

Answer (score 0):

In `/wp-admin/admin.php` on line 108:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    @ini_set( 'memory_limit', apply_filters( 'admin_memory_limit', WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT ) );
```

This could be why its for some admin users and not others.

You can set constants in the `wp-config.php` file in the root wp directory, like so:

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
```

However, you shouldn't really need to do that... it seems like there's something else going on..  Good luck.

Comment: If you're really desperate, find the do_action function, and echo the tag name.  You'll see a spam of all the action hooks that run, and you'll see where its bombing out.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  Yeah, I did edit the wp-config.php... I've been working on this for quite a while now and have been trying everything!  I'll give the do_action echo trick a go and see what shows up.  Thanks!

Comment: I found "function do_action()" in wp-includes/plugin.php and in a Twitter plugin, but since all my plugins are disabled, shouldn't Wordpress not need to call this do_action function?

Comment: Sorry, spoke to soon... added the echo and that function is definitely called by Wordpress, even with all plugins de-actived.  It dies at the following tag: wp_insert_post

Comment: So I've been following the do_action trail and did notice that it called "shutdown" at the end (just showed up after the memory error from my original question).  It seems like the post-new.php page completes, but never gets outputted to the screen, just the error instead.  I'm even more confused now.